# Update openshift env var while server is running and get the latest value of the same

Tags: node.js, openshift, openshift-cartridge

On openshift I have set env X=20. In my nodejs module I am reading this value but whenever I update the value for X I am not able to get the updated value. I have to restart the server in order to get the latest one.

Is there a way with which I can get the latest value of env variable without restarting the app?

While googling I have found following API which can help me..
https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/OpenShift_Online/2.0/html/REST_API_Guide/chap-Environment_Variables.html

Comment: According to [the RHC commands reference](https://developers.openshift.com/en/managing-common-rhc-commands.html#_commands_for_managing_environment_variables), *some* app servers load environment variables at boot so the restart seems to be required here.

Comment: Couple other options are to use database or file on local filesystem to store the value, then update and read from it when you need.  You can store files under process.env.OPENSHIFT_DATA_DIR.  However, I'd prefer to use database over filesystem.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately what you are trying to do is not possible.  The environment variables are set at the system level, and the application server (apache, etc) needs to be restarted to reload them.  As has been suggested in the comments, you should use a database or text file to store the information that you need to update & retrieve on the fly.